# searching objects in a class

Tags: java, class

I'm making a program, in school, that plays monopoly and I set up all the own-able properties as objects in the property class and I want to be able to search for the properties by their position value. so if the player's position is 3 (which is Baltic Ave. in my code) I want to be able to search all own-able properties for one with a position of 3 then have the player buy/pay rent for the property. Is this possible or should I go at the problem from a different angle?

```
public class property 
{
String owner;
int position;
int price;
int rent;

public property(int startPrice, int startPosition, int startRent)
{
    price = startPrice;
    position = startPosition;
    owner = "none";
    rent = startRent;
}

public void setOwn(String newOwn)
{
    owner = newOwn;
}
public void changePrice(int newprice)
{
    price = newprice;
}
public void changeRent(int newRent)
{
    rent = newRent;
}

public int getprice()
{
    return price;
}
public int getpos()
{
    return position;
}
public String getown()
{
    return owner;
}
public int getrent()
{
    return rent;
}
}
```

Comment: This is possible, but it would most naturally go through some kind of game-wide container for the instances of `property` -- an array or `List` of them, for example.  The `property` class itself does not need to provide for it.  And please, follow naming conventions: class names should begin with a capital letter -- `Property`.

Answer (score 0):

To start, I'd have some sort of data structure to keep track of properties that can be bought. A HashSet is best since order doesn't matter and you can add and remove elements quickly. Set it up so that it contains properties that can be bought. Then I'd make this method: (don't put it in your Property class)

```
private static Property getPropertyAtPos(Player player, HashSet buyableProperties)     {
    for(Property p : buyableProperties) {
        if(p.position == player.position) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Call this method to get the property that can be bought by that player. Hope this helps.